# interaction and dummy term interpretation WITH partial derivatives using inflection point

Tags: econometrics, interaction, interpretation, continuous-data

I have the following model for `returns` as a function of `firm_profitability`, `sentiment`, and additional predictors (included in the `Gamma * Z` term), with error term `e`.

`positive_sentiment` is a dummy variable representing `sentiment` > 0, so that the association between `returns` and `sentiment` can differ between positive and negative `sentiment` values.

```
returns = -0.23 + 0.91 firm_profitability + 
          0.32 sentiment  +
          0.52 (positive_sentiment * sentiment) +
          0.66 (sentiment * firm_profitability) +
          Gamma * Z + 
          e
```

Can someone please help me interpret the equation using the partial derivative with respect to sentiment? Can we interpret it as 1 unit increase in negative sentiment increases returns by 0.32, and when we interact sentiment with the positive sentiment dummy, the total impact of positive sentiment on returns is 0.84 (= 0.32 + 0.52)?

I also would like to find the inflection point where the effect of firm profitability changes direction based on the effect of sentiment interaction, as I see the negative and positive sentiments affect returns differently.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I just want to intrepret this regression by interms of positive sentiment and by effect of firm size on returns...i mean how returns are influenced by positive sentiment and firmsize , sentiment negative sentiment;;want to explain  while gamma represents control variable

Comment: It's not clear how `sentiment` differs from `positive_sentiment`. Is `sentiment` a continuous variable that can be either positive or negative, while `positive_sentiment` is a dummy that is 0 for negative `sentiment` and 1 for positive `sentiment`? If so, what were you trying to accomplish with the `positive_sentiment * sentiment` interaction term?

Comment: Sir the positive sentiment *sentiment is actually a variable  that has only has positive values of sentiment. So as this helps me to turn a simple 0 or 1  dummy variables into a dummy variable carrying positive values and actually depicting positive sentiment while negative sentiment is treated as zero, effectively portraying effect of positive and negative sentiment differently. My query is to find inflection point where effect of firm profitability changes direction based on effect of sentiment interaction., as I see the negative and positive sentiment effect returns differently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can we interpret [the coefficient for `sentiment`] as 1 unit increase in negative sentiment increases returns by 0.32?

Only if `firm_profitability = 0`, as you have an interaction between `sentiment` and `firm_profitability` that isn't restricted to positive values of `sentiment`. Within negative values of `sentiment`, a 1-unit change in `sentiment` means a change of `0.32+0.66*firm_profitability` in returns.

> when we interact sentiment with the positive sentiment dummy, the total impact of positive sentiment on returns is 0.84 (= 0.32 + 0.52)?

Again, only if `firm_profitability = 0` as that otherwise would still ignore the interaction term `0.66 (sentiment * firm_profitability)`. You need to take the `firm_profitability` into account. When a predictor is involved in an interaction, is has no single association with outcome unless you specify the values of all its interacting predictors.

> I also would like to find the inflection point where the effect of firm profitability changes direction based on the effect of sentiment interaction.

I take this to mean that you are looking for the level of `sentiment` at which the association between `returns` and increasing `firm_profitability` changes from negative to positive. The first derivative of `returns` with respect to `firm_profitability` is a function of `sentiment`: `0.91 + 0.66*sentiment`. This equals 0 when `sentiment = -0.91/0.66`, approximately -1.38. Note that this is below the value of 0 at which you allowed for a change in the association between `returns` and `sentiment`.

*In response to comment*

You can ask a related question: what's the level of `firm_profitability` where the association between `sentiment` and `returns` changes sign? In your model, that depends on whether `sentiment` is negative or positive.

For positive `sentiment`, the first derivative of `returns` with respect to `sentiment` is: `0.32 + 0.52 + 0.66*firm_profitability`. That equals 0 (sign of association switches) at approximately `firm_profitability = -1.27`.

For negative `sentiment`, the first derivative of `returns` with respect to `sentiment` is: `0.32 + 0.66*firm_profitability`. That equals 0 at approximately `firm_profitability = -0.49`.

Whether those predictions make sense depends on your understanding of the subject matter.

Specifying a sharp change in one part of the model at `sentiment = 0` while having the interaction between `sentiment` and `firm_profitability` independent of the sign of `sentiment` might be leading to predictions that don't represent reality well. You might consider a model that handles `sentiment` more smoothly, for example with regression splines, instead.

Comment: Thanks. You got ii. I also want the level of profitability at which sentiment changes from positive to negative or vice versa. I cannot comprehend the last line from note that; please  can you explain it as I have   many firms with different equations results.

Comment: secondly, if the interaction term is significant, then can we interpret sentiment as negative sentiment ? I mean if the interaction term is significant, then we can interpret that negative sentiment= sentiment

Comment: one more query, for calculating inflection point, does  we require both the values of 0.91 + 0.66*sentiment =-1.38 as significant or  significance does not matter. can you throw light from point of view of significance. I really appreciate your valuable contribution

Comment: @adarshad the point estimate of the "inflection point" won't change based on "statistical significance" considerations. You might determine confidence intervals based on the covariance matrix of the coefficient estimates and the formula for [variance of a weighted sum of random variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance#Weighted_sum_of_variables). The `linearHypothesis()` function in the R [`car` package](https://cran.r-project.org/package=car) can help with that. The practical significance depends on your knowledge of the subject matter.

Comment: what are your comments for below the allowed value of zero.Can you explain this?

Comment: @adarshad even with negative `sentiment`, your model allows for a large enough `firm_profitability` to outweigh a slightly negative `sentiment`. When you're trying to understand a model with interaction terms, it helps to try out and plot results for several _combinations_ of predictor values. You can't interpret implications of one predictor unless you specify the values of the predictors with which it interacts.

Comment: sorry one more.. what if value is positive(if we assume its positive), what does it will mean...Thanks for your contribution and help..

Comment: @adarshad I added a bit to the answer, assuming that you meant the value of `sentiment` is positive and wanted to evaluate where the association between `firm_profitability` and `returns` changes sign. I also showed the result when `sentiment` is known to be negative. If `firm_profitability > 0` then increasing `sentiment` is always associated with increasing `returns`. in your model the _magnitude_ of that association increases when `sentiment` goes from negative to positive.